# Netlogo: change turtle color from set of list with condition

Tags: list, colors, netlogo, any

I have this set of code. 
The agent is "consumers", where it has variable "type-of-value". I am trying to change white turtle into one of color on the list of "type-of-value". But I keep getting "expected a constant" error message.

```
to develop-needs
  if ticks mod 5 = 0 [
    ask consumers [set type-of-value  (list blue red green)] 
    let a count consumers with [color = white]
    if any? consumers with [color = white]
      [ set color one-of type-of-value ]
        ask turtles with [ color = one-of type-of-value ]
      ]]
end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Indentation is confusing here — is `ask consumers` inside `if ticks`, or isn't it? Is the `let a` inside the `ask consumers`, or isn't it? It'd be a lot easier to read, and give feedback on, your code if it were properly indented. (NetLogo will do it for you — select the code and press the Tab key.)

Comment: Edited indentation. And yes, consumers inside if ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code finally work.
Thanks to JenB I noticed my mistake.

```
to develop-needs
  if ticks mod 5 = 0 [
    ask consumers [set type-of-value  (list blue red green)] 
    let a count consumers with [color = white]
    if any? consumers with [color = white]
      [ ask n-of (random a ) consumers with [color = white]
        [set color one-of type-of-value
         set value? true]
         ]]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told it how many to select. That is, the `ask n-of a` needs to say (for example) `ask n-of 5 a` if you want to select 5 consumers from the agentset named a.

By the way, you also have a logic error in your code:

```
[ set color one-of type-of-value ]
  ask turtles with [ color = one-of type-of-value ]
```

If type of value is a list of 3 items (eg [blue green red] as in your code), then the `set color one-of` in the first line will choose one of those colors, but the second line `one-of ...` will do new random selections. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve so I can't provide code, but you will probably want to select a color and assign it to a variable then make your comparisons with that variable instead of doing further selections.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I attempt to change random number of white turtle (if any) into one of color on the list and assign it to variable. I edited the code. But still returned with error message

Comment: I re-edit the code with your hints. It works. Thanks.